# An application of Hartogs' theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

"The zero set $$Z(f) = \{ z \in U \vert f(z) = 0 \}$$ where $$U \subset \mathbb{C}^n \ \text{is open and the map} \ f: U \to \mathbb{C} \ \text{is holomorphic}$$ cannot be contained in a compact subset $K \subset U$ unless it is empty."

I have been trying to prove this statement by using [Hartogs' extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_extension_theorem), but I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, it can, if $Z(f) = \varnothing$ (or if $n = 1$). Otherwise, if $f \not\equiv 0$, consider the meromorphic function $1/f$.

Comment: I didn't write but we have $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose toward a contradiction that $Z(f) \subset K$ for a non-empty compact set $K \subset U$. Take a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $K$ such that $V \setminus K$ is connected. Then the function $1/f: V \setminus K \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and can thus, by the extension theorem, be extended to all of $V$. Now $f$ agrees with this extension on $V$, so since $V$ is open we have that they agree on all of $U$. But this is a contradiction since dividing by something cannot give zero.